How to prove if there is no Hamilton Cycle?
This picture should be a good example of no Hamilton Cycles:

I have checked multiple times and made sure there was no cycle, but I don't know how to prove that there is no cycle. Proving that there is one is easy; just list the path that shows it's real. However, I can't find a proper way of proving there isn't a cycle. How would I go about this?

Hi, I encourage you to post your previous question about DFS and BFS on CS SE (https://cs.stackexchange.com/) as I have an answer which you may find useful!

Greetings. I tried to but there appears to be a 40 minute timer. Could to possibly DM it if that's an option? I'll still post the question later.

Sounds good I will answer then.

I made the post. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/167644/how-to-represent-bfs-and-dfs-between-adjacency-matrix-and-list

Sorry, just saw this. I posted my answer. It may not be what you were looking for but I hope it could shed some light on more useful approaches to BFS with different data structures. Iterative algorithms are slow and often inefficient.

It was a great explanation. Thank you.

Have a look at vertex $d$. Since a cycle would need to go through $a$ and also $e$, the cycle must pass through vertex $d$ vertically. Similarly looking at $b,f,h$ you conclude that any hamiltonian cycle has to contain the outer square but none of the connectors $do$, $fm$, etc. This is a contradiction since it doesn't cover all vertices.
